# Getting 404 error on Eclipse che-dashboard hosted on GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, nginx-ingress, eclipse-che

I am getting 404 error on Eclipse-che dashboard hosted on GKE. PFA the screenshot

[image]

I have installed Eclipse-che on GKE using the following link:

https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/che-7/installation-guide/installing-che-on-google-cloud-platform/

This installed multiple services like che-dashboard, keycloak, plugin-registry, etc. **Out of these only che-dashboard is not loading. Rest all URLs are working fine.**

PFB the logs of ingress-nginx-controller:

```
122.175.207.163 - - [24/Jun/2021:06:24:44 +0000] "GET /dashboard/ HTTP/2.0" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36" 392 0.003 [eclipse-che-che-dashboard-8080] [] 10.112.2.2:8080 0 0.003 304 1c4a4882d31e464f404716dddca417d4
122.175.207.163 - - [24/Jun/2021:06:24:45 +0000] "GET /dashboard/assets/branding/branding.css HTTP/2.0" 404 548 "https://che-eclipse-che.peryton-ide.cloud/dashboard/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36" 117 0.000 [eclipse-che-che-dashboard-8080] [] - - - - a6f48841b0eaf5135fbe12a3996e33a1
122.175.207.163 - - [24/Jun/2021:06:24:45 +0000] "GET /dashboard/assets/branding/loader.svg HTTP/2.0" 404 548 "https://che-eclipse-che.peryton-ide.cloud/dashboard/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36" 76 0.000 [eclipse-che-che-dashboard-8080] [] - - - - 1f006d0af83f50a08bd77765880bbe95
122.175.207.163 - - [24/Jun/2021:06:24:45 +0000] "GET /dashboard/monaco.11cc4e4084a2c0e4e596.js HTTP/2.0" 404 548 "https://che-eclipse-che.peryton-ide.cloud/dashboard/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36" 52 0.000 [eclipse-che-che-dashboard-8080] [] - - - - 2e0e0c60b5c7197129b2103fcf1fdc38
122.175.207.163 - - [24/Jun/2021:06:24:45 +0000] "GET /dashboard/vendor.c969b02c53d99bb77562.js HTTP/2.0" 404 548 "https://che-eclipse-che.peryton-ide.cloud/dashboard/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36" 43 0.000 [eclipse-che-che-dashboard-8080] [] - - - - 1815c91a1900b9354efe024cfa37a56b
122.175.207.163 - - [24/Jun/2021:06:24:45 +0000] "GET /dashboard/client.9121c736a72949f90045.js HTTP/2.0" 404 548 "https://che-eclipse-che.peryton-ide.cloud/dashboard/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36" 42 0.000 [eclipse-che-che-dashboard-8080] [] - - - - ccde33e64a256bb1e8e99af2badd0863
122.175.207.163 - - [24/Jun/2021:06:24:54 +0000] "GET /dashboard/ HTTP/2.0" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36" 25 0.001 [eclipse-che-che-dashboard-8080] [] 10.112.2.2:8080 0 0.001 304 39b78c0228c7dd747645eff6138fea47
122.175.207.163 - - [24/Jun/2021:06:24:54 +0000] "GET /dashboard/assets/branding/branding.css HTTP/2.0" 404 548 "https://che-eclipse-che.peryton-ide.cloud/dashboard/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36" 41 0.000 [eclipse-che-che-dashboard-8080] [] - - - - c211ae32e0e57d05c8d540b67b9078b0
122.175.207.163 - - [24/Jun/2021:06:24:54 +0000] "GET /dashboard/assets/branding/loader.svg HTTP/2.0" 404 548 "https://che-eclipse-che.peryton-ide.cloud/dashboard/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36" 39 0.000 [eclipse-che-che-dashboard-8080] [] - - - - 4a263c63680bec043ebb031063e6581d
122.175.207.163 - - [24/Jun/2021:06:24:55 +0000] "GET /dashboard/monaco.11cc4e4084a2c0e4e596.js HTTP/2.0" 404 548 "https://che-eclipse-che.peryton-ide.cloud/dashboard/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36" 42 0.000 [eclipse-che-che-dashboard-8080] [] - - - - bf5b25a3b34c1576f405d3a76ba23f96
122.175.207.163 - - [24/Jun/2021:06:24:55 +0000] "GET /dashboard/vendor.c969b02c53d99bb77562.js HTTP/2.0" 404 548 "https://che-eclipse-che.peryton-ide.cloud/dashboard/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36" 43 0.000 [eclipse-che-che-dashboard-8080] [] - - - - 29ba29737982c2073521ab58412cd7ef
122.175.207.163 - - [24/Jun/2021:06:24:55 +0000] "GET /dashboard/client.9121c736a72949f90045.js HTTP/2.0" 404 548 "https://che-eclipse-che.peryton-ide.cloud/dashboard/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36" 42 0.000 [eclipse-che-che-dashboard-8080] [] - - - - 3dd2f904fd517e2c9e6854f34ef2d626
122.175.207.163 - - [24/Jun/2021:06:25:21 +0000] "GET /dashboard/ HTTP/2.0" 200 696 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36" 327 0.004 [eclipse-che-che-dashboard-8080] [] 10.112.2.2:8080 696 0.003 200 bc6b62ef78ed151b65f21420447db7bb
122.175.207.163 - - [24/Jun/2021:06:25:21 +0000] "GET /dashboard/assets/branding/branding.css HTTP/2.0" 404 548 "https://che-eclipse-che.peryton-ide.cloud/dashboard/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36" 117 0.000 [eclipse-che-che-dashboard-8080] [] - - - - 12d95a6cd384505d0e601fdf7e60ec7b
122.175.207.163 - - [24/Jun/2021:06:25:21 +0000] "GET /dashboard/monaco.11cc4e4084a2c0e4e596.js HTTP/2.0" 404 548 "https://che-eclipse-che.peryton-ide.cloud/dashboard/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36" 52 0.000 [eclipse-che-che-dashboard-8080] [] - - - - 773a6a94eec8c435b48f7be2c50ece8a
122.175.207.163 - - [24/Jun/2021:06:25:21 +0000] "GET /dashboard/vendor.c969b02c53d99bb77562.js HTTP/2.0" 404 548 "https://che-eclipse-che.peryton-ide.cloud/dashboard/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36" 43 0.000 [eclipse-che-che-dashboard-8080] [] - - - - c7a8c2beefc42106d9d94dd6acc28563
122.175.207.163 - - [24/Jun/2021:06:25:21 +0000] "GET /dashboard/assets/branding/loader.svg HTTP/2.0" 404 548 "https://che-eclipse-che.peryton-ide.cloud/dashboard/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36" 76 0.000 [eclipse-che-che-dashboard-8080] [] - - - - a5edd02999071f7397dcaf0124259086
122.175.207.163 - - [24/Jun/2021:06:25:21 +0000] "GET /dashboard/client.9121c736a72949f90045.js HTTP/2.0" 404 548 "https://che-eclipse-che.peryton-ide.cloud/dashboard/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36" 42 0.000 [eclipse-che-che-dashboard-8080] [] - - - - bc0d9b881f53074e9d0eda5f6873a735
```

I have already tried to restart the pod serving che-dashboard by deleting it, kubernetes restarted it. Also I have changed the path in Ingress from / to /*, with no luck.

Please help me in fixing this. I can provide more information if needed.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of it is that dashboard deployment is not reachable, probably due Ingress misconfiguration.

> Also I have changed the path in Ingress from / to /*, with no luck.

which one?
Please try https://stackoverflow.com/a/68080963/9365723 if you haven't.
If it does not work, let me know and we'll try to find a solution.

Comment: Hi @Serhii. I already implemented the solution you provided to edit /dashboard/* to /dashboard/ on che-dashboard-ingress, and it fixed the 302 redirect issue. But I ran into this 404 error right after that. And to answer your question, I have made this / to /* path change in che-ingress. There are two separate ingresses for che app and dashboard. I hope I am making sense.

Comment: Do you want to see my ingress YAML file? I can paste it as an update on the question.

Comment: no / -> /* change is needed. https://github.com/eclipse-che/che-server/blob/main/deploy/kubernetes/helm/che/templates/ingress.yaml#L43
Will you be able to try the latest helm chart? 
I can take a look your Ingresses yaml but no guarantee I'll catch issue there =)

Comment: Hi @Serhii, I tried to deploy the latest helm chart in the last couple of days and I am running into all kinds of errors. Please point me in the right direction. Apologies for the trouble, I am working with Kubernetes and helm charts for the first time. This is the command I last executed to upgrade the helm charts: '$ helm upgrade che-ingress che-ingress.yaml -f https://github.com/eclipse-che/che-server/blob/main/deploy/kubernetes/helm/che/templates/ingress.yaml'

Comment: So the problem is specifically with ingress-nginx-controller because che-dashboard service logs are returning 200 Ok. Please let me know if I should still try to upgrade the helm chart. Should I trash this whole thing and do a fresh install from the beginning of eclipse-che multiuser on Google kubernetes engine?

Comment: @zeeshan07 sorry for delay. I don't use helm charts often, but I expect you upgrade your installation with similar command you used to install it. updating che ingress may be not enough.
If possible, deploying from scratch would be easiest way

Comment: Sure @Serhii, Let me do the install again and I'll let you know.