# 404 Error Eclipse Che on GCP - URL Dashboard Blank Screen

Tags: eclipse-che

@serhii-leshchenko & other eclipse-che users - I configured eclipse che and unfortunetly I see an absolute blank page when I use the URL after this step https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/che-7/installation-guide/installing-che-on-google-cloud-platform/ (Install Che on Google Cloud Platform)

[error picture - click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JY09S.png)
[blank screen dashboard picture - click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdgJa.png)

I found someone similar facing this but the tips and tricks were not useful [Getting 404 error on Eclipse che-dashboard hosted on GKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68111471/getting-404-error-on-eclipse-che-dashboard-hosted-on-gke)

All the URL's work i.e. Plug-in Registry, Identity Provider URL except the dashboard url https://che-eclipse-che.XXX-XX.com

Answer (score 0):

these days I don't have time to prepare well-detailed answer, but here are some links:

- I assume it's caused by https://github.com/eclipse/che/issues/19914#issuecomment-853687040
- note helm charts are not supported anymore and are fully dropped

to make it working you would need to play with dashboard ingress and find the right configuration. After you archived that - please drop an issue to make Che Operator supporting custom dashboard ingress path to work on different ingress controllers.

Answer (score 0):

This is what fixed this bug for me on K8s 1.20 and 1.21:

kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.2.1/deploy/static/provider/aws/deploy.yaml

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.